# Testing with Jest in React Native Navigation with different Stacks depending on Redux State

Tags: react-native, redux, jestjs, react-navigation

I'm currently developing a React Native Expo app using Redux for state management and React Navigation for navigation. I'm trying to write Jest tests to ensure that the right screen is displayed based on the onboarded state in my Redux store. The state gets set after some asynchronous calls, but I mocked its implementation. How to test if the right screen gets displayed after the state is set to true?

I have two different navigation stacks based on that onboarded state in my app. Here is my implementation:

```js
const RootNavigationContainer = () => {
  const onboarded = useAppSelector(selectOnboarded);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        {!onboarded ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="OnboardingStart"
              component={OnboardingStartScreen}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="LoginEmail"
              component={LoginEmailScreen}
              options={{ animation: "none" }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="SignUpEmail"
              component={SignUpEmailScreen}
              options={{ animation: "none" }}
            />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="BottomTabNavigation"
              component={BottomTabNavigation}
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

How to check if the BottomTabNavigator is focused and not the LoginEmailScreen?

Here is my current test:

```js
it("should navigate to the home screen when a user is onboarded", async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = renderWithProviders(
      <LoginEmailScreen navigation={navigation as any} route={mockRoute} />
    );
    onboarded = true;
    fireEvent.changeText(getByTestId("email-input"), "test@test.de");
    fireEvent.changeText(getByTestId("password-input"), "test");
    fireEvent.press(getByTestId("login-button"));
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(checkIfOnboarded).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

And my mocked implementations:

```js
jest.mock("./script.ts", () => ({
  signInWithEmail: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (email, password) => {
    if (email === "" || password === "") {
      return "Email or password is empty";
    }
    if (email === "test@test.de" && password === "test") {
      return;
    } else {
      return "Email or password is incorrect";
    }
  }),
  checkIfOnboarded: jest.fn().mockImplementation((userId) => {
    if (userId === "mockUserId") {
      return [
        { categories: [], name: "", username: "", savedPosts: [], avatar: "" },
      ];
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }),
}));

let onboarded: boolean;

const getUserMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(async () => {
  if (onboarded) {
    return { data: { user: { id: "mockUserId" } } };
  } else {
    return { data: { user: { id: "notOnboardedId" } } };
  }
});

supabase.auth.getUser = getUserMock;
```

And my implementation of the LoginEmailScreen:

```js
const loginConfirmed = async () => {
    setSignInButtonDisabled(true);
    const errorMessage = await signInWithEmail(email.trim(), password.trim());
    const {
      data: { user },
    } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
    if (!errorMessage && user) {
      dispatch(addUserData({ user: user.id }));
      const onboarded = await checkIfOnboarded(user.id);
      if (Object.keys(onboarded).length > 0) {
        // set logged in to true
        dispatch(
          addUserData({
            categories: onboarded[0].categories,
            name: onboarded[0].name,
            username: onboarded[0].username,
            savedPosts: onboarded[0].saved_posts
              ? onboarded[0].saved_posts
              : [],
            avatar: onboarded[0].avatar,
            onboarded: true,
          })
        );
        setSignInButtonDisabled(false);
      } else {
        navigation.navigate("Onboarding", { user: user.id });
        setSignInButtonDisabled(false);
      }
    } else {
      setError("error");
      Keyboard.dismiss();
      setSignInButtonDisabled(false);
    }
  };
```